# How to test PO assumption in complex survey data (svyolr) in R?

Tags: ordered-logit

I need to test the proportional odds assumption of an ordinal logistic regression of complex survey data.  The model is estimated using `survey::svyolr()`.  How can I use test the PO assumption of this `svyolr` model?

I've found several options for non-survey weighted data (for example those estimated using `MASS::polr()`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to implement them for complex survey data estimated with `svyolr()`. Examples of PO tests for ordinal logistic regression models that are not complex-survey adjusted :

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brant/brant.pdf
https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/166205/ThomasA_TheProportionalOddsModel.pdf?sequence=1